# Let $n$ be a positive integer. Suppose that $2^n$ and $5^n$ begin with the same digit. What is the digit?

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Suppose that $2^n$ and $5^n$ begin with
>   the same digit. What is the degit?

I have a bit of difficulties to start the problem. Is anyone is able to give me a hint? Please I ask you to don't give me the solution to the question; I want to resolve by myself.

I have already know the method which is the simple mechanics; it's not interesting. The method in which we test some value of $n$, and finally we find $n=5$ respecting condition.  I would just have a more clever method. It could be any other number other than the three that meet the condition. Is anyone is able to find a rigorous and interesting method. I already know the hint $2^n 5^n = 10^n$, but I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: If two numbers have the same first digit $d$, what first digit(s) can their product have?

Comment: I have already consider this hint, but I don't know how to isolate and work just the simple digit I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that
$$ 2^n = (c+r_1)\cdot 10^u,\qquad 5^n = (c+r_2)\cdot 10^v \tag{1}$$
with $c\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and $r_1,r_2\in [0,1)$. $(1)$ implies:
$$ 10^n = (c+r_1)(c+r_2)\cdot 10^{u+v} \tag{2}$$
hence $c$ may only be the first digit of $\sqrt{10}$, i.e. $3$, or the first digit of $\sqrt{100}$, i.e. $1$.

The second case is easy to exclude as pointed by Nate in the comments.

Comment: $(c+r_1)(c+r_2)$ can't actually be 100 if $c \le 9$ and $r_i<1$, so the second case doesn't actually happen.

Comment: how did you exclude $4$ ?

Comment: @Nate: exactly, the second case is easy to exclude.

Comment: @mercio: we do not need to exclude $4$, it is not the first digit of $\sqrt{100}$ or $\sqrt{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

The first digits of the powers are NOT periodic, the period eventually breaks
down :

```
? for(j=0,100,print1(digits(2^j)[1]," "))
1 2 4 8 1 3 6 1 2 5 1 2 4 8 1 3 6 1 2 5 1 2 4 8 1 3 6 1 2 5 1 2 4 8 1 3 6 1 2 5
1 2 4 8 1 3 7 1 2 5 1 2 4 9 1 3 7 1 2 5 1 2 4 9 1 3 7 1 2 5 1 2 4 9 1 3 7 1 3 6
1 2 4 9 1 3 7 1 3 6 1 2 4 9 1 3 7 1 3 6 1

? for(j=0,100,print1(digits(5^j)[1]," "))
1 5 2 1 6 3 1 7 3 1 9 4 2 1 6 3 1 7 3 1 9 4 2 1 5 2 1 7 3 1 9 4 2 1 5 2 1 7 3 1
9 4 2 1 5 2 1 7 3 1 8 4 2 1 5 2 1 6 3 1 8 4 2 1 5 2 1 6 3 1 8 4 2 1 5 2 1 6 3 1
8 4 2 1 5 2 1 6 3 1 8 4 2 1 5 2 1 6 3 1 7
```

So, the argument with the period is not valid, but Jacks proof seems to be complete.